# Phpmailer could not authenticate after i changed server ip?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

After i created new server application (new application is copy of old) with new IP adress i can't anymore send mails from same code and same authentication.

I am getting:

> SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o2sm6648795wjo.3 - gsmtp
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.site.co SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [178.62.1.7]250-SIZE
>   35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250
>   SMTPUTF8 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready
>   to start TLS CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.site.co SERVER ->
>   CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [178.62.1.7]250-SIZE
>   35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
>   OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250
>   SMTPUTF8 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN SERVER -> CLIENT: 334
>   VXNlcm5hbWU6 CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   cHJlZGljdG9sb2d5c3lzdGVtQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== SERVER -> CLIENT: 334
>   UGFzc3dvcmQ6 CLIENT -> SERVER: Nm5iNURydjs= SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   534-5.7.14
>    Please log in via your web browser
>   and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 o2sm6648795wjo.3 - gsmtp
>   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14
>    Please log in via your web browser
>   and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 o2sm6648795wjo.3 - gsmtp
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SERVER ->
>   CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection o2sm6648795wjo.3 - gsmtp SMTP
>   connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

and code is:

```
include_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
function sendmail($body){
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                  // SMTP password

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only

$mail->From = 'from@from.net';
$mail->FromName = 'Site';
$mail->AddAddress('to@yahoo.com', 'To');  // Add a recipient

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Site: New unmapped teams found!';
$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $body;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: may be it could help you restart the apache and try it worked for me

Comment: @jothi Same report is again :/

Comment: //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; comment this line and try it

Comment: Did you try reading the error message and doing what it says?

Comment: @jothi Same is when i comment tls, when i change to ssl i get SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server.

Comment: @Synchro Yes i checked everything. I allowed less secure apps, display unlock captcha. I created new mail but again it is same. It works when i switch to old application, it looks like old application is linked with gmail and new one is not.

Comment: SOLVED! I just created new Host email account and assign new client account in Accounts and Imports.